# I am getting an error during post request to an api in mongodb database

Tags: database, mongodb, api, rest, react-fullstack

{
"msg": {
"index": 0,
"code": 11000,
"keyPattern": {
"address": 1
},
"keyValue": {
"address": "Jaipur"
}
}
}
This is the error occuring while trying post request on my api.

I changed the unique property to false. But I am still getting the error

Comment: Might need to manually drop/recreate the index jn MongoDB via the shell